# Is it possible to use CHECK validation in Prisma models?

Tags: postgresql, prisma

I have a table that can be created with this SQL code

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "user" (
  id int GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  name username NOT NULL,
  email email NOT NULL,
  password text NOT NULL,
  email_verified bool NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
  verify_email_code text,
  verify_email_code_exp_date TIMESTAMPTZ,
  created_at TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
  updated_at TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
  CHECK (length(name) >= 3),
  CONSTRAINT unique_user_name UNIQUE (name),
  CHECK (length(email) >= 3),
  CONSTRAINT unique_user_email UNIQUE (email)
);
```

Here I'm checking length of `name` and `email`, and if length of either of them is less than 3 characters - the whole data will be rejected.

1. How can I define this exact model with Prisma?
2. If it isn't possible, what are workarounds?

Comment: How do you manage your database schema?

Comment: At first I had just an SQL file to create all the tables, but I assume with Prisma I should use Prisma CLI to define tables and manage them afterwards. I don't have strong opinion on which approach is better. @some-user

Comment: If you continue to use your SQL file (or use any migration tool that supports raw SQL) you should be fine. No need to have the `CHECK` in your prisma schema. Just have it in your database schema.

Comment: @some-user you mean I can create the schema with SQL file and then use Prisma, but without migrations using Prisma CLI ?

Comment: yes, for example

Answer (score 1):

As of 2023, it's not possible:

> Check constraints are currently not included in the generated Prisma schema - however, the underlying database still enforces the constraints.
> https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/other/advanced-database-tasks/data-validation/postgresql#2-adding-a-table-with-a-single-check-constraint-on-a-single-column

You'll have to create a custom migration: https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/migrate/developing-with-prisma-migrate/customizing-migrations

Open issue to support `CHECK`: https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/3388